# Procedure not printing anything

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc AS
CURSOR v_cursor IS

BEGIN
  FOR obj IN v_cursor LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(obj.player ||'         '|| obj.No ||'         ');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This is the procedure that i have written.... When i comile it the procedure gets created but when i try and execute the procedure....

Procedure succesfully completed but nothing prints....

Would appreciate the help...!!!

Cheers

Edit: The query runs fine and i get the desired result...!!!

Comment: Does the `SELECT` return results?

Comment: yes it does.... the query runs fine

Comment: AFAIK to_char is an oracle function and it doesn't exist in mysql.

Comment: It seems to me that you're using oracle, not mysql.

Comment: i just forgot to do the server out...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1) Check if your query is indeed
 returning some rows.

2) Make sure SERVEROUT IS ON (SET SERVEROUTPUT ON)
 or use dbms_output.enable(buffer_size => NULL);